# netbeans "Please wait - classpath scanning in progress..."

Tags: java, netbeans

When i try to compile netbeans projects i get this message/error :
"Please wait - classpath scanning in progress..."

and nothing happens , its like you have have to wait for enternity to conmpile "hello world"...

Now the first thing is that we have moved to a new office building, but the laptop is the same. It's a very secure enviroment with a lot of "security", can't connect anywhere almost.
Also i have changed the user dir in netbeans.conf to save my data in c:\Program Files\User

Any ideas how to fix this?
alrady tried reinstalling netbeans, changing save location between standart and newone...

Comment: Found out the solution, for some reason i had few (like 3) Netbeans Projects folders, and netbeans was scanning all of them and freezing, deleted 2- probl;em solved

Answer (score 2):

Just some ideas to find the problem

- Look at the CPU - is netbeans busy (100% on one core) or blocking (95% idle)?
- Standard, ant or maven build? Where are your libraries and do you use absolute or relative paths?
- Start with a simple "hello world" project (no dependencies), then add one lib (log4j or something similiar), located in a project folder and - if this works - move that lib to other locations (choose locations similiar to the libs on the real classpath)

There is a chance, that you don't have access rights to the folders/shares that contain your libraries. Or, as you mentioned security, that some virus scanner blocks access to some *highly dangerous* libs...

Comment: 1.netbeans uses 2-5% CPU ~95% idle :) but when time passes(after like 5 min) ram usadge increases from 200mb to 440mb and CPU usadge increases 6-16%?!                       2. Standart build libraries in standart places...                3.Hello world doesn't compile at all ...

Comment: after like 18 minutes netbeans uses 0.5gb ram; program compiled, cpu back to ~3 %?!

Comment: @user615927 - unfortunatly not - and I must admit, I'm no netbeans expert, eclipse is what I know. I was hoping that my post helped identifying the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all the files under the .netbeans/7.0/modules directory. Although I lost some configurations of the IDE, it started to work pretty fine.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

Answer (score 1):

I followed Andreas-d advise... after disabling the antivirus and restarting netbeans everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

This seems interesting issue as per you have specified ! Somewhere, the netbeans documentation writes that the issue has already been resolved. However, for your information please have a look on : [Scanning Project Classpaths takes too long](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47415)

This link may or may not be helpful to you. But, the discussion may provide chance to resolve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when adding JavaFX libraries in my project: properties >> libraries >> Compiler Tab >> Classpath option, I have accidentally added my root user (C:\users\paulo) along with the JavaFX jar files. That was making NetBeans to scan basically my whole harddisk. The solution was very simple: just to go back there in properties >> libraries >> Compiler Tab >> Classpath option >> Edit button and deleted that "c:\users\paulo" and almost immediately the scanning processes went away.