# Scanning project netbeans does not stop

Tags: java, netbeans

i've a problem while compiling my project in netbeansn it always show that message and nothing happens after: “Please wait - classpath scanning in progress…”. I waited for too long to see if it's going to run or not but in vain. I tried all solutions even those who are in the following link : [netbeans "Please wait - classpath scanning in progress..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990432/netbeans-please-wait-classpath-scanning-in-progress?rq=1)

but still have the same prob : netbeans "Please wait - classpath scanning in progress..."

I've even uninstalled the netbeans but nothing changes. If anyone could help me i wlill really be thankful. I'm using netbeans 7.0.1

Comment: Maybe upgrade your netbeans? They're on v8.0.1 now.

Comment: Try to check if it is really scanning.  Sometimes the message is left on screen even when scanning stops.

Comment: @proulxs I'm upgrading now from 7.0.1 to 8.0.1

Comment: @markspace i'm having a progress bar, it blocks a little at 63% and then complete 100%. Afte this a scanning projects starts without endind

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy all project files (make a backup somewhere)
2. Remove all projects
3. Launch netbeans
4. Import from backup

Comment: I did but the problem is still there, scanning in progress

Comment: @user3862042 just shout down your pc and star it again

Comment: I did but nothing happened